# Action Script 3.0: Stop Drag with hittestobject

Tags: actionscript-3

how to stop drag(event) the object with hittestobject.. thanks.

```
object.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_BEGIN, drag);
object.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_END,drop);
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loop);

function drag(e:TouchEvent):void {
  e.target.startTouchDrag(e.touchPointID);
}
function drop(e:TouchEvent):void {
  e.target.stopTouchDrag(e.touchPointID);
}
function loop(e:Event):void {
  if (object.hitTestObject(collision)) {
    //code to stop drag event?
  }
}
```

or is there other way to stop drag event aside from function drop?

sorry for my bad english.

//edited

Comment: The code would just be `object.stopTouchDrag()`.

Comment: i tried that but it has an error, error says:"incorrent number arguments. expected 1."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the function drop() e.target is the object that currenty processes the event. In the function loop() you also have some objects. It is not clear which of them is dragging but you should call either object.stopTouchDrag() or collision.stopTouchDrag().

UPDATE

There is an argument for both startTouchDrag and stopTouchDrag functions - touchPointID, it is used to determine what touch point (of many) is processed. When stopping the drag, you need to use the same touchPointID which was used for starting it. When calling the stopTouchDrag from a non-event context, you can't know what touch point it should use. So you need to remember it somehow. If your target object is a MovieClip you can just add a dynamic property to it and save the touchPointID there:

```
function drag(e:TouchEvent):void {
  (e.target as MovieClip).touchPointID = e.touchPointID; 
  e.target.startTouchDrag(e.touchPointID);
}

function loop(e:Event):void {
   if (object.hitTestObject(collision)) {
      object.stopTouchDrag(object.touchPointID);
   }
}
```

Comment: sorry, i forgot to add object to addeventlistener. but thanks for understanding..   when i tried your code, it has an error on that line. it says, "incorrent number arguments. expected 1".

Comment: Forgot about the argument. I have updated my answer, please see it.